# Replace serializationinfo in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have to get info about serialized object. Normally I would use `SerializationInfo` but that class is missing in `WP7.5`.

Which class you can suggest me?

Comment: What type of serialization, XML?

Answer (score 0):

How are you serializing your object?  Been a while since I've touched the WP side, but can't you / shouldn't you just implement a ToBytes()/FromBytes() on your object and manually write/read the pieces of your object(s), perhaps w/ a BinaryReader?

Comment: It's been a while since I ask that question, I don't remember what I want to do but at 99% percent it was something with MySQL base, so now I will use linq.